# Having issues syncing Firebase Cloudstore documents to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I have been following this guide -

https://websiddu.com/blog/sync-data-from-firebase-to-google-sheets.html

What I am trying to do is to sync each newly created document in my collection to Google Sheets. I've deployed everything according to the guide with success, but unfortunately my Sheets are not updating.

I've changed my Sheet ID and service account json to the correct names, as well as replace "product" with the name of my collection.

Any ideas on how to do this? I'm running the scripts on gitpod.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's important that you share your Spreadsheet with the service account, otherwise the cloud function will not be able to write to the sheet.

You can share the sheet with a email id that looks like `bla-bla@fir-to-sheets-289e1.iam.gserviceaccount.com` by clicking on the share button on the top right of your sheet and make sure the account has edit access and then press share.